# How to distinguish between manually triggered and auto triggered jobs in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins

I have a multijob in jenkins which gets triggered after another job is finished.

Say there is a **"main"** build job and the multijob **"parent"** is dependent on it. Parent doesnt have any build steps, it has 3 child jobs - **"child1", child2", "child3"**. **"Child2"** is UI testsuite.

The **"main"** job runs periodically and if its successful, it will call invoke **"parent"** job which will eventually trigger all children jobs. Also, the parent job has independent periodic run schedule.
What I want to achieve is - if the **"child2"** job is invoked automatically by Jenkins, it should inject the UI credentials from Jenkins credentials plugin. However, if **"child2"** job is triggered manually, it should use the personal credentials provided by the invoker.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

use the Jenkins build parameters. And set the default values. So, when the job is invoked automatically it will use the defaults.

For manual executions, replace the default values by typing in the one that you want the job to use.

Comment: Which parameter in particular? Are you talking about "Started by" parameter? I tried to use that. But problem is, its the main job that is triggered either manually or automatically. So if I check "invoked by" at the child level, regardless of trigger type, it always shows parent job name and build number.